# Does node's readFile() use a single Buffer with all the file size allocated?

Tags: node.js, file-io, stream, filesystems, buffer

I'm quite new to Node and filesystem streams concerns. I wanted to now if the readFile function maybe reads the file stats, get the size and create a single Buffer with all the file size allocated. Or in other words: I know it loads the entire file, ok. But does it do it by internally splitting the file in more buffers or does it use only a single big Buffer? Depending on the method used, it has different memory usage/leaks implications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here on chapter 9.3:

http://book.mixu.net/node/ch9.html

As expected, readFile uses 1 full Buffer. From the link above, this is the execution of readFile:

// Fully buffered access
[100 Mb file]
-> 1. [allocate 100 Mb buffer]
-> 2. [read and return 100 Mb buffer]

So if you use readFile() your app wiil need exactly the memory for all the file size at once.

To break that memory into chunks, use read() or createReadStream()